# Angularjs - Not able to collapse particular div when scroll to particular div position on click on particular link

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have some div coming from ng repeat and also some menu coming from ng repeat.On pageload here my divs are collapsed except first div.When I click on any menu above it will scroll to particuer div. Here the problem is all divs are remain open after clicking on any menu.Actually only particular scrolled div should open and others should closed.can anyone please help me,I am new to angularjs.Here is the code below and also updated in plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/MRZgVHYMWsff022Mq3dV?p=preview

### HTML

```
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <style type="text/css">
    .scroll-div {
      height: 100px;
      overflow: scroll;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .anchor {
      border: 2px dashed red;
      padding: 10px 10px 200px 10px;
    }
    .my-fixed-header {

    }
    .my-fixed-header > a {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 5px 15px;
    }
  </style>
 <body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
   <div class="my-fixed-header">
      <a href="index.html#/#anchor{{x}}" href="" ng-click="gotoDiv(x)" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5]">
        Go to Div {{x}}
      </a>
   </div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="item.value" ng-change="onTextChange()">
    <div class="scroll-div">

      <div style="border:1px solid;" id="anchor{{group.id}}"  ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:item.value ">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open(group)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

### index.js

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$location,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.open = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a ===item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = !a.isOpen;
    });
    $scope.closeOthers(item);

  }
$scope.onTextChange = function(item) {

       if($scope.item.value){
          $scope.groups.forEach(a=>{
            a.isOpen = true;
          });
       }
       else{
          $scope.groups.forEach(a=>{
            a.isOpen = false;
          });
          $scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
       }
  };

  $scope.closeOthers = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a !==item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = false;
    });
  }
$scope.gotoDiv = function(x) {



          $scope.groups.forEach(a=>{
            a.isOpen = true;
          });


     };

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      id:'1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      id:'2',
      list: ['item1b',
        '<b>item2b </b> blah ',
        'item3b'] 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      id:'3',
      list: ['item1c',
        '<b>item2c </b> blah ',
        'sss3c'] 

    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      id:'4',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      id:'5',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    }
  ];
$scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
});
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me,I am new to angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue and updated on the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/MRZgVHYMWsff022Mq3dV?p=preview

### HTML & CSS

```
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>

<style type="text/css">
    .scroll-div {
      height: 100px;
      overflow: scroll;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .anchor {
      border: 2px dashed red;
      padding: 10px 10px 200px 10px;
    }
    .my-fixed-header {

    }
    .my-fixed-header > a {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 5px 15px;
    }
  </style>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div class="my-fixed-header">
      <a ng-repeat="y in players" href="index.html#{{y.technology}}"  ng-click="gotoDiv(y)" >
        Go to Div {{y.technology}}
      </a>
   </div>
<select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
<option value="technology"><p>view by</p>-<p>technology</p></option>
<option value="vertical">vertical</option>
</select>
<div><button>Sort-ascending alphabetical order</button></div>
<div><button>Sort-descending alphabetical order</button></div>

<div class="scroll-div">
<div style="border:1px solid;" ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: attr" ng-attr-id="{{key}}">
  <h4>Group name: {{ key }}{{value.length}}</h4>
 <div  ng-repeat="group in value">
  <div class="parents"  ng-click="open(group)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> Title        
        </div>


  <div ng-attr-id="{{key}}" class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen" style="height:70px;">
    player: {{ group.name }} 
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

### script.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['angular.filter']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.oneAtATime = true;
$scope.players = [
    {
      name: 'projectjava',
      symptom:'fever',
      technology:'java',
       vertical:'insurance',      
      id:'1'
    },

    {
      name: 'projecttabulue',
      symptom:'diesease',
      technology:'tabulue',
       vertical:'Banking',    
      id:'2'
    },
    {
      name: 'projectpython1',
      symptom:'diesease',
      technology:'python',
       vertical:'Health care',    
      id:'3'
    },
    {
     name: 'projectpython2',
      symptom:'colds',
      technology:'python',
       vertical:'Banking',    
      id:'4'
    }

    ];
    $scope.players[0].isOpen = true;
     $scope.update = function() {      
  if($scope.x == 'technology'){
   $scope.id='technology';
    $scope.attr = 'technology'; 


   }
   if($scope.x == 'vertical'){
   $scope.id='vertical';
   $scope.attr = 'vertical';    
   }
   }
   $scope.open = function (item) {
    $scope.players.filter(a=> a ===item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = !a.isOpen;
    });
    $scope.closeOthers(item);

  }
$scope.gotoDiv = function(y) {
          $scope.players.forEach(a=>{
          console.log(a.technology);
          if($scope.x == 'technology'){
              if (a.technology === y.technology.toString()) {  
            a.isOpen = true;
             }
               else{
          a.isOpen = false;           
      } 
}     
          });  
     };
  $scope.closeOthers = function (item) {
    $scope.players.filter(a=> a !==item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = false;
    });
  }

});
```